# Special form in CSS

Tags: css

How I can create a special form like the below in CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.form{
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: darkorange;
  position: relative;
}

.form::after{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 120px 120px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='form'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-radius`.

HTML

```html
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <p>Hello!</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  background-color: orange;
}

#main {
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px; /* Set height so the border shows */
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0; /* Set border radius (how much the border curves) */
  padding: 25px; /* Add padding so the text stays inside of the curved border
}
```

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2j1zuy70/5/